# how to create an api to push form input data into mongodb document as a subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, subdocument

can this be done with fetch api which method should i use post or put? please reply.. can someone please give me the complete api to push orderSchema as a subdocument in userSchema i have scrolled tons and tons of links still i am not able to find any answer too this

this is the schema i am using in mongo db.

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose'
    const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        rsph: { type: Number },
        rcyl: { type: Number },
        raxis: { type: Number },
        lsph: { type: Number },
        lcyl: { type: Number },
        laxis: { type: Number },
        add: { type: Number },
        frame: { type: String },
        lens: { type: String }
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    });
    
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        phone: { type: Number, required: true },
        address: { type: String, required: true },
        orders: [orderSchema]
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    });
    
    export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

I am using this api to save userschema and this is working.

```
    import initDB from '../../helper/initDB';
    import User from '../../models/addUser';
    
    initDB()
    
    export default async (req, res) => {
      (req.method)
      {
        "POST"
        await handler(req, res)
      }
    }
    const handler = async (req, res) => {
      if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log(req.body)
        const { name,phone,address } = req.body
        let u = new User( {name,phone,address } )
        await u.save()
        res.status(200).json({ success: "success" })
      }
      else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "this method is not required" })
      }
    }
```

I am using this api to save this data as a subdocument but this api is not working what changes should i make?

```
    import initDB from '../../../helper/initDB';
    import User from '../../../models/addUser';
    
    initDB()
    
    export default async (req, res) => {
      (req.method)
      {
        "POST"
        await handler(req, res)
      }
    }
    const handler = async (req, res) => {
      if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log(req.body)
        const { uid } = req.query
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: uid })
        const { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens } = req.body
        const order = ({ rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens });
        user.orders.push(order);
        await user.save()
        res.status(200).json({ success: "success" })
      }
      else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "this method is not required" })
      }
    }
```

please reply...

Answer (score -1):

Remove `bracket ()` from the below line.

```
const order = ({ rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens });
```

only pass the object, as

```
const order = { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens };
```

The final should be as:

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
      if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log(req.body)
        const { uid } = req.query
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: uid })
        const { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens } = req.body
        const order = { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens };
        user.orders.push(order);
        await user.save()
        res.status(200).json({ success: "success" })
      }
      else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "this method is not required" })
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now it is giving me this error. 
  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: undefined }" (type Object) at path "_id"

Comment: Possibly you may not be passing valid ObjectId at

`const { uid } = req.query
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: uid })`

Check that if `uid` is a valid `ObjectId`

Comment: Hey bro i've pushed the repository to Github pls look inside the api folder there i've made a folder of users inside it there is a file named orders i am not able to find which params i have to give to findbyidandupdate plz can u help me fix it link to repo  -: https://github.com/Sarab71/Git-optics

Comment: Api link :- https://github.com/Sarab71/Git-optics/blob/main/pages/api/user/orders.js

Comment: Form link :- https://github.com/Sarab71/Git-optics/blob/main/pages/user/%5Bid%5D.js

Comment: Do you have **User** database ready? @sarabnoor

If yes, use any **User _id** from there and pass it to your API call.

Also, please mark my answer as useful if it made sense to your question.

Comment: But how do i add a variable in id so that everytime when i add a subdocument it get saved to their parent document